# Accessing Native features in Hybrid app

Tags: android, ios, cordova, ibm-mobilefirst

Lately I came to know that native features such as camera etc can be accessed by hybrid apps using cordova plugin, but i can't seem to find the tutorials.

And for using this plugin do we need to know Java (for Android) and Objective-C for (iOS)? 
And is there documentation for cordova plugin like JQuery with some example to learn from?

Answer (score 3):

Cordova is bundled within Worklight. This means that you can use any API provided by Cordova... for example, to access the camera. All you need to do is to simply use [the Cordova Camera API directly in the app](http://docs.phonegap.com/en/3.1.0/cordova_camera_camera.md.html#Camera).

Note that Cordova's API uses `JavaScript` and not `Java` nor `Objective-C` (and for most cases you do not need to know these programming languages).

You should read the following to better understand the above:

- [IBM Worklight Getting Started training materials](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html)
- [Using Cordova in Worklight applications](http://www.ibm.com/developerworks/mobile/worklight/getting-started.html#cordova)
- [Cordova APIs](http://cordova.apache.org/docs/en/3.1.0/index.html)

The tutorials also explain how to create a native Cordova plug-in (in Objective-C or Java), but what you do in it is solely native code and is not something Worklight can teach you... you need to learn this on your own(!).

Comment: Thnx for the Info =D !! But the contents in IBM website Aren't That usefull though :/ ... I have written 3 apps in Worklight with just jq and HTML .. and Learning jquery was easy by looking at its api ..
Now am working in on an app that needs fb Oauth and needs to use Fb api too and i was said that it could be used using cordova plugins .
Is there anywhere i can find tutorials on how to use cordova for the above prob ?

Comment: The training materials also provide samples.

Comment: Note that you DO NOT need to know Java or Objective-C to use the native camera in your app... please see my updated answer.

Comment: @DhayalanPro, is your question resolved?

Comment: @DhayalanPro, if my answer helped resolve your problem, please mark as fixed